# Uniqueness of Extended Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm doing a bit of extra reading on the Extended Euclidean Algorithm and had a side-thought that I couldn't find an answer to in the book.

I understand that the Extended Euclidean Algorithm can express the GCD of two numbers as a linear combination of those two numbers.

My question is, is the linear combination acquired unique? (My gut is telling me that it not, but I'd like some verification as I cannot produce a proof of uniqueness).

If the answer is 'No', then my follow-up question is "What is so special about the specific linear combination acquired by the EEC?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given two integers $a$ and $b$, the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) calculates the $\gcd$ and the coefficients $x$ and $y$ of [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity): $ax+by=\gcd(a,b)$. These coefficients are not unique (see linked article).

The specific coefficients created by the algorithm satisfy these conditions: $$|x|<|\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}|$$
$$|y|<|\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}|$$

Answer (score 4):

The Extended Euclidean Algorithm finds the solution closest to the origin.

Comment: See for instance https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.120.06.562

Answer (score 1):

If there is one solution $(x,y)$ of the *linear diophantine equation* $ax+by=c$ then  there are infinitely many, given by $(x-\dfrac b{\rm{gcd}(a,b)}t,y+\dfrac a{\rm{gcd}(a,b)}t)$ for any integer $t$.

There will be a solution at all if and only if $c$ is a multiple of the $\text{gcd}$.