# Bezout's identity: which half is larger?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

Bezout's identity: Let a and b be integers with greatest common divisor d. Then, there exist integers x and y such that ax + by = d.

Is it true that if a > b then ax < by? Is there a proof for this?

Comment: This is a little confusing, since one of $x$ and $y$ must be negative if $a$ and $b$ are both positive.

Answer (score 2):

$x,y$ are not uniquely defined.  Let $a=2,b=1$.  Then we could take $x=1, y=-1$, which makes your inequality false.  Or we could take $x=-1.y=3$ which would make it true.

Note:  In the comments, the OP has made clear that $x,y$ are intended to be the "minimal" solution, that is, the solution generated by the Euclidean Algorithm.  In my example, the minimal solution is, of course, $x=0, y=1$ for which the claim holds.  But even with this extra requirement, however, the general claim is false.  For $a=3,b=2$, the minimal solution is $x=1,y=-1$, say.

Comment: probably worth mentioning that, if $a,b$ are positive, unless $a|b$ or $b|a,$ then one of $x,y$ is positive and the other negative.

Comment: @WillJagy  Sure, though a priori the OP might imagine that, in that situation, we always needed $x<0, y>0$  (which, to be sure, we don't).

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about the Extended Euclidean algorithm. Are x, y uniquely defined in that?

Comment: @user5464854  Ah.  The coefficients generated by Euclid are indeed well defined, in fact they are the "smallest" solutions. You can read more about that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1001199/uniqueness-of-extended-euclidean-algorithm).